# How to find and replace string in a file with a variable in Shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I want Shell script to find my `Orignal_literal` and change it with dynamic literal, this literal would be runtime input to script.

Answer (score 0):

`sed -i "s/Orignal_literal/c \\$variable/g" file.txt`

Explanation:

- `sed` = Stream Editor
- `-i` = In-place (i.e. save back to the original file)
- The command string:

  - `s`: The substitute command
  - `Orignal_literal`: A regular expression
    describing the word to replace (or just the word itself)
  - `g`: Global (i.e. replace all and not just the first occurrence)
  - `variable`: Runtime variable
  - `file.txt`: The file name

Comment: What's the `c\\ ` for?